# How to change the default encoding to UTF-8 in Windows Terminal App(UWP)

Tags: utf-8, windows-terminal

I'm using the files that are encoded with UTF-8 but the default encoding for me is EUC-KR(chcp 949), I want to know the way that adapts the UTF-8 as the default encoding of my terminal(automatically when the terminal starts). I'm using *PowerShell core 7.0.2*. I don't want to type "chcp 65001" anymore when I start it.

Answer (score 2):

In `settings.json` for Windows Terminal, you can launch Powershell with a command. Make your Powershell profile look something like this:

```
{
    "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
    "name": "Windows PowerShell",
    "commandline": "powershell.exe -NoExit -Command chcp 65001",
    "hidden": false
},
```

**Note about icons**: As of the time this was written if you are using a Powershell profile with a `guid` different than the default`{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}` You will loose the Powershell icon in the launch menu unless you specify another custom icon file or set the icon file back to the system default by setting the `icon` property in your `settings.json` Powershell profile like this:

`"icon": "ms-appx:///ProfileIcons/{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}.png"`